# Writing to texture from CUDA using surf2Dwrite

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda, textures

I'm calculating colour values in CUDA, that I want to write in a texture for OpenGL. Regardless of the actual colour value, the texture contains only symbols (Í). Hence the displayed texture is just black.

1. How do I go about debugging this? (no errors when colpiling, running or using compute-sanitizer)
2. Am I wrong in using uchar4 type?
3. Am I using the surface object correctly? (unfamiliar with those)
4. Is there a "better" way to update the texture?
5. Should I use two textures per iteration? (One to write to, one to read from in GL)
6. Are there any resources/tutorials on using CUDA surfaces/resources other than the [programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html?highlight=surf2dwrite#surface-object-api)? (I need a little more to understand those fully)

The relevant code:

```
// initialize texture
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

  glGenTextures(1, &texture_1);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_1);

  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, window_width, window_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
  checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&cuda_resource_1, texture_1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsWriteDiscard));
  memset(&cuda_resource_desc_1, 0, sizeof(cuda_resource_desc_1));
  cuda_resource_desc_1.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
```

```
// starting the kernel
  size_t num_bytes_1, num_bytes_2;
  cudaArray *resArray_1, *resArray_2;
  cudaSurfaceObject_t surf_object_1, surf_object_2;
  
  checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &cuda_resource_1, (cudaStream_t)0));                                  
  checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(&cuda_tex_array_1, cuda_resource_1, 0, 0));
  cuda_resource_desc_1.res.array.array = cuda_tex_array_1;                                                          
  checkCudaErrors(cudaCreateSurfaceObject(&surf_object_1, &cuda_resource_desc_1));                                  
  colour_kernel<<<grid, block, shared_memory_size>>>(surf_object_1, solvent_radius, window_width, window_height); // run kernel and update texture 1
  checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &cuda_resource_1, (cudaStream_t)0));
```

```
// kernel
  int x = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
  int y = (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y;

  if (x > width || y > height)
    return;

  uchar4 data = make_uchar4(0.0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5);
  surf2Dwrite(data, surface, x * sizeof(uchar4), y);
```

```
// test function to read the texture and write it to a txt file
void writeTextureToFile(GLuint texture, int size)
{
    uchar4 *data = new uchar4[size];
    glGetTextureImage(texture, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, size * sizeof(uchar4), data);

    // access the data
    std::ofstream myfile("test.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            myfile << data[i].x << ", " << data[i].y << ", " << data[i].z << ", " << data[i].w << "\n";
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Unable to open file" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: For resources, take a look at the official [CUDA samples](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/master).

Comment: I've realized something else, `GL_RGBA` in conjunction with `GL_FLOAT` requires a `float` quadruple as data. Each component will be stored in a `float`.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of uchar4 seemed to be the problem. With some trial and error and google I figured out a working solution with float values using GL_RGBA32F_ARB (for the glTexImage2D). Still not sure why uchar would not work (I found some other examples online that utilized uchar).